# Vertical align text with carriage return next to image in the middle with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I can't get the text below to vertical align next to an image with a space in between two pieces of text.  There is always this whitespace.  If I remove the image itself, the lines work correctly.

```
<td class="document-header">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 0" src="http://localhost:2222/assets/images/2771?w=75&amp;h=75" alt="Basketball Tournament Tournament">
                                    <div style="display: inline; text-align: left">
                                        <h1 style="display: inline;">
                                            Basketball Tournament Tournament
                                        </h1>
                                        <br/>Apr 23-24, 2014
                                    </div>
                        </td>
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use break tags for spacing. Wrap the second text in  proper text element and use margins and padding to position it. Also, it looks like you are using tables for layout...another no-no.

Comment: I tried a div before with same issue.

Comment: A div is not a text element.

Comment: Can you recommend an element?  Googling "html text element" doesnt bring up anything.

Comment: Love the downvote with no reason posted.

Comment: I have to use tables, this is for PDF generation where tables are recommended to use.  It is a report created using ABC PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zX7bm/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-75-75-6.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Main Heading</h1>
        <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrap .text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The h1 tag has a huge space at the bottom just like my current situation?

Comment: This actually works, I had the wrong display type, so instead of display:inline I used display:block with the <br/>

Answer (score -1):

Using your own HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/Mr34r/1/

```
<td class="document-header">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 0; display:inline-block;" src="http://localhost:2222/assets/images/2771?w=75&amp;h=75" alt="Basketball Tournament Tournament">
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left">
         <h1 style="display: inline;">
            Basketball Tournament Tournament
        </h1>

        <br/>Apr 23-24, 2014
    </div>
</td>
```

**Edited.**

Comment: It puts it right to the right of the <h1>.  I want it right underneath left aligned.

Comment: @MikeFlynn I edited, try now, it should work. Works as intended on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mr34r/)

Comment: It's <br/> and for some reason that doesn't work for me.  It's my original code above.

Comment: I need the image with the text centered.  This will move the image to the left of the text leaving a huge whitespace.  Also you need to look at this link on the <br/> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp.  Your fiddle also highlights it as being incorrect.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Sorry, you were right on `<br />`. I updated again my answer for your problem. The text should properly rap around it now.